# Copying contents of one file in reverse into another file

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I have the below code, I am trying to write contents of one file in reverse into another file

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <conio.h>
# include <process.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *f1,*f2;
    char file1[20],file2[20];
    char ch;
    int n;
    printf("Enter the file1 name:");
    scanf("%s",file1);
    printf("Enter the file2 name:");
    scanf("%s",file2);
    f1=fopen(file1,"r");
    f2=fopen(file2,"w");
    if(f1==NULL || f2==NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Characters to read from end of file :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    fseek(f1,-n,SEEK_SET);
    while(!feof(f1))
    {
        ch=fgetc(f1);
        fputc(ch,f2);
    }
    fcloseall();
    getche();
```

But after execution , contents are not written in reverse order but it is copied as it is, I have used

```
fseek(f1,-n,SEEK_SET).
```

I am not sure where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Determine the length of `file1`:

```
fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_END);
int file1Length = ftell(file1);
```

Write contents of `file1` to `file2`, in reverse:

```
for(int filePos = file1Length; filePos >= 0; filePos--)
{
    fseek(file1, filePos, SEEK_SET);
    fputc(fgetc(file1), file2); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fiddling Bits :)

Comment: @user3027039 Any time.

Answer (score 2):

The `fgetc` in your loop works forwards. To read backwards, you need an additional `fseek(f1, -2, SEEK_SET)` in your loop.

You need `-2` because you need to rewind back over the single character you just read, and then another position to get to the character before that.

I don't think you need the line

```
 fseek(f1,-n,SEEK_SET);
```

at all -- you need to read *from* the end of your file. This positions the file pointer to the correct position for the very last character to write (in reverse). You want

```
fseek(f1,0,SEEK_END);
```

(and then you have to think about what I said above).

It would be far easier a task if you simply read in the required number of characters into a temporary buffer and write that in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Below program prints the file in reverse order on console. Instead of console, you can write it into another file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(void)
{
    char c;
    FILE *ifp, *fp2;
    char *fileName="a.txt";
    ifp= fopen(fileName, "rb");/* binary mode for ms-dos */
    fseek(ifp,0L, SEEK_END);/* move to end of the file */
    fseek(ifp,-1L, SEEK_CUR);/* back up one character */
    do
    {
        c = fgetc(ifp);/* move ahead one character*/
        putchar(c);
        fseek(ifp,-2L, SEEK_CUR);/* back up twocharacters*/
    } while (ftell(ifp)>0); 
    c = fgetc(ifp);/* move ahead one character*/
    putchar(c);
    fclose(ifp);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```